Windows 10上でbatchファイルが正常に実行できない原因が知りたい
質問内容
提示コードを実行するとコマンドプロンプトが以下のようになってしまう原因わかりません。
知りたいこと
以下のbatchファイルが正常実行されない原因が知りたい
行ったこと
１．行番号を特定のため、
２．'〇〇､' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 などの文字から特定しようとしましたが、そもそも存在しない場所や、文字が途切れている？のでどこが原因で、どこで止まっているのか掴めません、
３．文字コードを変更しましたが、依然として似たような表示がされます。
４.ChatGPTを使って調べました。
５．以前は実行出来たのですが、久しぶりにクローンして実行すると下記の文字化け問題が発生します。
※追記
自分でしたプログラムで以前は自分の環境で実行出来ていました。
６．文字コードをUTF-8 Unix(LF)(ウインドウズ付属のメモ帳上から確認) からSHIF_JISに変換
７．実行はされますが結果がおかしいという現状の詳細を掴みました、
知りたいこと
文字コードの問題？で正常に実行されない原因と対処方法が知りたい
現状
異常実行されてしまう
環境
OS：ウインドウズ10
コンパイラ: g++
ビルドツール：cmake,ninja
コマンドライン：ウインドウズ既定のコマンドプロンプト
プロジェクト状況
二つのプロジェクトが存在しています。

library
.libファイルを生成

test
libraryで生成した.libファイルを使ってテストを行うプロジェクト


コマンドプロンプト
>start.bat
'ild_dir' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'ｴ蜷医・菴懈・' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'ake縺ｮ螳溯｡・cmake' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'繝峨′螟ｱ謨励＠縺溷ｴ蜷医・蜃ｦ逅・if' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'test' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'r' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'貞炎髯､' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'S' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'-----------' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
ld: unrecognized option '--config'
ld: use the --help option for usage information
'config' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'粋縺ｮ蜃ｦ逅・if' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'-----' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'ho.' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'############' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
'せ繝亥ｮ溯｡後ヵ繧｡繧､繝ｫ縺ｮ螳溯｡・start' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

start.bat
@echo off

set CURRENT_DIR=%~dp0

set library_dir=library
set test_dir=test

set library_build_dir=%CURRENT_DIR%%library_dir%\build
set library_project_dir=%CURRENT_DIR%%library_dir%

set test_build_dir=%CURRENT_DIR%%test_dir%\build
set test_project_dir=%CURRENT_DIR%%test_dir%


echo.
echo.
echo ====================== library project ======================
echo.



rem ビルドディレクトリが存在しない場合は作成
if not exist %library_build_dir% (
    mkdir %library_build_dir%
)

rem ビルドディレクトリの中身を削除
rem rd /s /q %library_build_dir%

rem CMakeの実行
cmake -S %library_project_dir% -B %library_build_dir% -G "Ninja"

rem CMakeの実行が失敗した場合の処理
if %errorlevel% neq 0 ( 
    echo ----------- cmake failed. -----------
    exit /b 1
)

rem cmake --build %library_build_dir% --config Release
cmake --build %library_build_dir% --config Debug

rem ビルドが失敗した場合の処理
if %errorlevel% neq 0 ( 
    echo ----------- build failed. -----------
    exit /b 1
)


echo. 
echo. 
echo ====================== test project ======================
echo. 

rem ビルドディレクトリが存在しない場合は作成
if not exist %test_build_dir% (
    mkdir %test_build_dir%
)


rem ビルドディレクトリの中身を削除
rd /s /q %test_build_dir%


rem CMakeの実行
cmake -S %test_project_dir% -B %test_build_dir% -G "Ninja"


rem CMakeの実行が失敗した場合の処理
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo ----------- cmake failed. -----------
    exit /b 1
)


rem cmake --build %test_build_dir% --config Release
cmake --build %test_build_dir% --config Debug

rem ビルドが失敗した場合の処理
if %errorlevel% neq 0 ( 
    echo ----------- build failed. -----------
    exit /b 1
)

echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ###################### all build success. ######################
echo.

rem テスト実行ファイルの実行
start %test_build_dir%\game_project.exe


もしかしたらこの記事あたりが該当するかも？ 最新Windowsでのファイル名の文字コードの扱いに注意 あるいは加えて各種パスの途中に空白を含むフォルダ名があるとか？ ちなみに設定や環境が変だったり問題があっても、関連するすべてのフォルダ名を全角/空白/記号を含まない英字だけのものに変更すれば回避できるかもしれませんね。 他にはこんな記事も。Windows10のコードページについて調べてみた, Windows10のUTF8化(ベータ機能)試した結果をさくっと こちらは作成したプログラムについてなので別ですが参考になるかも。MINGW64で作ったC++プログラムで正しく日本語を扱いたい

「以前は実行出来たのですが、久しぶりにクローンして実行すると」ということは、自分で書いたバッチファイルではなく、GitHub 等で公開されているものを使用しているということでしょうか？

原因
改行コードがLFになっている
対処方法
改行コードをCRLFに変更する
今回は新しいバッチファイルを作成してVSCode上でコードをコピペしました。
なぜそうなったか？
原因は不明なのですが、以前は自分で構築した制作環境で正常に実行でき、このような問題は起きなかったのですが、おそらくGitHub上で変更されたものだと考えられます。
※追記：
コメント欄での指摘通りGitHub上で変更される(確定情報)
参考(コメント欄より)：
バッチをgitに上げてそれを他の人がクローンすると、なんか動きませんけどと言われる(gitにコミット時の改行の扱いについて)

gitにはcore.autocrlfという設定があり、チェックアウト時にCRLFへ変換する機能があります。それを有効化していないとLFのままチェックアウトされるでしょう。

Windows上でGitを使う場合のTIPSらしいですね。以前と今回で違う設定だったのかもしれません。バッチファイルが実行できないと思ったら改行コードがLFになってた, 気をつけて！Git for Windowsにおける改行コード, 【Git】改行コードが自動変換されてしまう対処法〜Windowsでチェックアウト・コミット時の注意, [バッチ/git] バッチをgitに上げてそれを他の人がクローンすると、なんか動きませんけどと言われる(gitにコミット時の改行の扱いについて)

「クローンして実行」というのはどこかからバッチファイルをコピーして作成したということでしょうか？
文字コードが UTF-8 Unix(LF) になっていたというのが良くわかりません。
元々 Unix（Linux）上で動作していたコマンドをWindows用に書き換えたということでしょうか？
エクスプローラで新規ファイルを作成してそれをメモ帳で開いてコードを入力して保存・実行したらどうでしょうか？
※ 9/27 8:50
申し訳ありません メモ帳は使ったことがなかったのですが、デフォルトで UTF-8 になっているのですね。ANSIに変更して保存してください。
※ 9/27 8:50　ここまで
テキストはコピー貼り付けしてかまいません。
１行目の @echo off を @echo on にして実行すればエラーになったコマンドがわかります。
必要なら途中に pause 文を入れて確認しながら実行してください。
気になる点
(1) 最後の行で start xxx.exe としていますが、なぜ start が必要なのですか？
また、この start は自分自身(start.bat)をさすのではありませんか？
たぶん 途中の exit /b で終了しているのでここまで到達していないのでしょうが
(2) ファイルのパスは空白やコマンドとみなされる特殊文字（& { < >）等を含んでいないのですか？
もし含んでいる場合はパスを ""で囲む必要があります。
例えば下記のようにします。
if not exist "%library_build_dir%" (

※ 9/27 8:50
参考までに特殊文字の参考URLを記述しておきます。
cmd | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd
この中の解説に以下の記述があります。
次の特殊文字を引用符で囲む必要があります:
& <> [ ] | { } ^ = ; ! ' + , ` ~ [空白]
※ 9/27 8:50　ここまで
以上。
